# Simplifying beautifulsoup table data extraction

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am attempting extract 2 specific rows of data from a website table that eventually can be replicated over many pages that contain all the same the same tables with different data.

Being very new to python I am using BeautifulSoup to initially extract the data.

So far my code includes this:

```
for td in tfoot:
    td =td.find_all('td')
    row = [i.next for i in td]
        print(row)
```

which shows

```
['Subset', '2', '\xa0']
[<b>Total A</b>, <b>213</b>, <b>96</b>, <b>137</b>, '\xa0']
['Total B', '224', '92', '152', '\xa0']
```

I only need the numerical values from row 2 and 3 and have tried variations of [1:] in different lines of my code etc to exclude the first row that hasn't worked

Having the `<b>` tag in one row has thrown up additional problems for me extracting just the numbers from the 2 rows

My next attempt was to find the numbers from each row separately using this

```
for td in tfoot:
    if td.get_text().find('Total A') > -1:
        row = [i.next for i in td]
        print(row)
```

Whilst that works when run for 'Total A" and "Total B" it seems very messy, and it doesn't help me ignore the  tags so I'm left only with the numerical values.

Comment: Could you provide sample structure or website url, please

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to extract tables from html is just using pandas and then saving the rows you want to keep, because if the web changes it can find the tables anyway:

```
import pandas as pd
from requests import get

html_web = get('website to scrap')

# Here pandas stores in a list all the tables present in the website
tables = pd.read_html(html_web.text)

# Now just select the table you want to procces
table_to_save = tables[0]

# Now just keep the rows you want to save as dataframe, np.array, list...
# In this case I will select the rows containing some sting as
# np.array of the values of the 2 rows
selected = table_to_save[table_to_save[table_to_save.columns[0]].str.contains("Total A") |  table_to_save.columns[0]].str.contains("Total B")].values
```

Just test it. Hope it works for you. If you give me the website you want to scrap I can make code for it.

Comment: I added the open bracket after the pipe but got `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'str'

Comment: I expected learning to use pandas was my next step to learning this but wanted to try bs4 first to add to my knowledge and tools. Would love to see how you would build this. An example page is ('https://afltables.com/afl/stats/games/2022/010820220320.html').

Comment: This url isn't avaliable